# Is there a way to retrieve the dimensions of a texture after binding with gl.bindTexture?

Tags: opengl, dart, webgl

I have a function that loads textures from a server into my WebGL context like this:

```dart
Future<Texture> loadTexture(String path) {
  return new ImageElement(src: 'assets/' + path)
    .onLoad.first.then((e) {
      var texture = _gl.createTexture();
      _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, texture);
      _gl.texImage2DUntyped(TEXTURE_2D, 0, RGBA, RGBA, UNSIGNED_BYTE, e.target);
      _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, NEAREST);
      _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
      _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_WRAP_S, CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      _gl.texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_WRAP_T, CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      _gl.generateMipmap(TEXTURE_2D);
      _gl.bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, null);
      return texture;
    });
}
```

However in order to map my texture coords from pixels to `0,0 - 1,1` I need to know the actual size of the texture. I don't want to introduce a class to return from this function if the dimensions can easily be retrieved given the `Texture` returned by this code.

Is there any way to retrieve the coordinates of the to directly from the WebGL [Texture](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-web_gl.Texture)?

I'm aware I can get them from the source `ImageElement`, but the API would be nicer if I could avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (at least in JavaScript WebGL, not sure about Dart WebGL bindings).

In OpenGL 3.x and OpenGL ES 3.1, the getTexLevelParameter API call with a GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH / _HEIGHT parameter makes it possible to retrieve the texture dimensions for a specific level of detail for the currently bound texture. This API call is not available in WebGL (1 or 2, WebGL 2 being based on OpenGL 3.0 only).